# iTunesConnect Technical users can upload binary files?

Tags: iphone, binaryfiles, app-store-connect

i'm a new iPhone developer and i'm working for a new company which ordered me an application. They are registered with the developer account and they added me with a Technical user role! My application is ready, now i need to implement and test the in-app purchase functionality because inside this app there are buyable contents.
I have all the certificates and i tried the application on my iPhone and everything seems to go very well, so i: 
1. created a new app through itunes connect
2. downloaded the application loader program to upload the binary files of the application in which i will implement the in-app purchase

If i understand, to upload binaries i need a distribution certificate, but when i am inside my developer section, i can't see the corresponding "distribution" form. The apple guide says : "Only Team Agents are authorized to prepare and submit applications for distribution.", so if i'm a simple developer inside the company i can't upload any app ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The binary needs to be *signed* with the distribution certificate, and embedded.mobileprovision must be an App Store distribution provisioning profile.

However, IIRC, to test In-App Purchase, you just need to create the app on iTunes Connect and add the relevant In-App Purchases; I don't think you actually need to upload a binary.

Comment: So you say that the Agent can create the certificate and he can sends it to me. So i use that distribution certificate to upload the binary?
Abount this: "you just need to create the app on iTunes Connect and add the relevant In-App Purchases; I don't think you actually need to upload a binary.", i created a new app with itunes connect, but the app state is "Waiting For Upload" and i can't add anything with iTunes Connect then Application Loader too.

Comment: You use certificates/keys to *sign*, not to *upload*. You can sign with the distribution certificate provided you also have the corresponding key.